# How to check if the field contains any alphabetic letters in Postgresql?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a text field on my Postgresql database that I want to store only numeric characters and special characters, like '-' and '.', and I have to delete all the rows that contains alphabetic letters from the database. How can I do this, i.e, find all the rows that contains alfabetic letters on a specified field?

Comment: Please clarify your meaning of "remove all rows". Does that mean delete those rows. Or does that mean correct the values. If correcting does the result need to be valid numeric value (so - must be leading or trailing only and just 1 and a single whole number decimal value separator).  Also is it necessary to adjust for decimal point (i.e. 99.00) vs. decimal comma (i.e. 99,00)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [PostgreSQL Regex](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html). That code must solve your problem.

```
select * from your_table where (column_text ~* '[a-z]') is false
```

`~*` matches a regular expression with case insensitive, and `[a-z]` represent all letters from a to z.

Answer (score 5):

To match any Unicode letter, instead of `[a-z]` or `[A-Za-z]`, you can use `[[:alpha:]]`:

```sql
select * from your_table where (column_text ~* '[[:alpha:]]') is false
```

The `[:alpha:]` is a POSIX character class that matchaes any Unicode letters. It is handy since PostgreSQL regex does not support Unicode category classes like `\p{L}` or `\p{Alphabetic}`. Seee [*9.7.3.2. Bracket Expressions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS):

> Within a bracket expression, the name of a character class enclosed in
> `[:` and `:]` stands for the list of all characters belonging to that
> class. A character class cannot be used as an endpoint of a range. **The
> POSIX standard defines these character class names: `alnum` (letters and
> numeric digits), `alpha` (letters), `blank` (space and tab), `cntrl`
> (control characters), `digit` (numeric digits), `graph` (printable
> characters except space), `lower` (lower-case letters), `print` (printable
> characters including space), `punct` (punctuation), `space` (any white
> space), `upper` (upper-case letters), and `xdigit` (hexadecimal digits)**.
> The behavior of these standard character classes is generally
> consistent across platforms for characters in the 7-bit ASCII set.
> Whether a given non-ASCII character is considered to belong to one of
> these classes depends on the collation that is used for the
> regular-expression function or operator (see Section 24.2), or by
> default on the database's LC_CTYPE locale setting (see [Section 24.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html)).
> The classification of non-ASCII characters can vary across platforms
> even in similarly-named locales. (But the C locale never considers any
> non-ASCII characters to belong to any of these classes.) In addition
> to these standard character classes, PostgreSQL defines the `word`
> character class, which is the same as `alnum` plus the underscore (`_`)
> character, and the `ascii` character class, which contains exactly the
> 7-bit ASCII set.

Answer (score 2):

(Alternative) In Postgresql:

To get the rows that contain at least a single letter:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE column_name SIMILAR TO '%[a-zA-Z]+%';
```

To get the rows that contain only letters and at least a single letter:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE column_name SIMILAR TO '[a-zA-Z]+';
```

In these snippets [a-zA-Z] means a single letter, + means at least once, % means whatever