# Is there a way to use a regular expression with the unicode category in Postgres?

Tags: regex, postgresql, plv8

I have a table with a `username` field and want to allow only letters, but include letters from all languages (including Umlauts). So I added a `check` to that field with a regular expression.

That’s where the [unicode category](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) would be perfect: `\p{Letter}`

Unfortunately, [unicode categories are not supported by postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

I tried creating a PLV8 function that uses the syntax, but it seems that PLV8 doesn’t support it either.

Is the only option to actually list all the characters?

Comment: This seems to be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59309954/724039, see also [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZQ9Q9CCI).   Or can you show examples that are not working?  (Please add those to your question )

Comment: Why not  use POSIX character classes? Use `[[:alpha:]]`

Comment: I was about to write, that both your answers do not take into account that I need to match letters from all languages because [a-z] only matches the latin alphabet, but you dbfiddle proves me wrong... This is not what JavaScript does, how can I write a JS regex then that matches this behaviour in JS then?

Comment: Ah.. I just checked the dbfiddle again and it doesn’t actually do what I thought it does. So your answer missed my need to match international letters too @Luuk

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you’re right, `[[:alpha:]]` does seem to be exactly right. Do you mind adding it as an answer, then I’ll accept it.

Comment: no need for an answer, because that would be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59309954/724039

Comment: @Luuk that's the wrong answer and doesn't work for my question.

Comment: This is the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75421167/170851